# Jupyter notebook deprecation warning in finding the root of the determinant of a matrix

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook, scipy-optimize

Given a matrix A, in which some of the elements are functions of x, find x such that det(A) = 0.

I started with a 5x5 diagonal matrix, shown in the code. The root function actually gave the right root (x = 1.562) but with

> DeprecationWarning: Conversion of an array with ndim > 0 to a scalar is deprecated, and will error in future. Ensure you extract a single element from your array before performing this operation.

```
def test(x):
    A = np.zeros((5,5))
    for i in range(5):
        A[i,i] = x**2-4+x
    return np.linalg.det(A)

root(test, 3)
```

However, if we just want the determinant, running `test(3)` is totally fine. I have no idea how this warning comes out and how to avoid it. I'm guessing there might be something to do with the root finding function, but I'm not sure how exactly. I'm afraid when the size of the matrix becomes very large, it won't find the true root. Has anyone have experienced similar problems? Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source code for root](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.11.4/scipy/optimize/_root.py#L25-L252) you will see that it calls `_root_hybr` if no method is provided. Going to `_root_hybr` we can see that there is [this line](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/5e4a5e3785f79dd4e8930eed883da89958860db2/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L224):

```
x0 = asarray(x0).flatten()
```

This converts your input `x0` which is `3` to an array, `array([3])`, so now your input to `test` is an array with `ndim=1` rather than the scalar you provided. So when you compute `x**2-4+x` this is also an array of `ndim=1` rather than the scalar you might expect. The warning is stating that setting an element of an array with an array with ndim>0 is deprecated, so it won't work in the future. To avoid the warning and the future error, within your function you need to convert `x` back to the scalar value your function expects which you can do with `x = x.item()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's really helpful. I read the `item` documentation. It only returns the specified element as a scalar, which indeed solved my problem. Furthermore, assuming the elements are functions of multiple variables in the original question, I can unpack them, `x1, x2, x3 = x`, in the `test` function. Having this idea back to the single variable question, I found that `x = x[0]` also solved the problem. Comparing `x = x.item()` with `x = x[0]`, not sure which is more efficient and robust though.

Comment: Item would be more robust if you only have a single scalar x0, as it would raise an error if you somehow ended up with an array with more than 1 element.